two tables share the same unique ID but with their own set of data. power pivot shows the same sum for each record even after creating relationship
I have two tables. one table has unique values while the other table has records based on those unique values. I added them to a data model and then made a pivot table. my intention was to find sum of each rate from the first table for each unique ID and name from the second table. however the sum is all the same instead of the sum to each unique ID.
what am i doing wrong? how do i get to my "desired pivot"?

I tried changing the relationships and moved around the items in the rows and columns of the pivot.

Quickest option is to create a Calculated Column in Table4 with:
=RELATED(Table3[rate])

And then use this column for your rate in your pivot.
The best (correct) option is to create Measures for your values.
Income $ := SUM(Table4[income])

Rate % :=
CALCULATE(
  MAX(Table3[rate]),
  CROSSFILTER(Table3[ID], Table4[ID], Both)
)
// or SUM(...) depending on what you need

CROSSFILTER(..., BOTH) will allow you to use the ID column from either table.
